# How to connect radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, call

So I am trying to build a basic Federal Tax Calculator and I have built them all (Single/MFJ/HOH) separately but I am trying to combine them. I have built the radio buttons, here is the code for the buttons:

```
<div id="status">
<input type="radio" id="Single" name="status" value="Single" checked="checked"> Single
<input type="radio" id="MFJ" name="status" value="MFJ"> Married Filing Jointly
<input type="radio" id="HOH" name="status" value="HOH"> Head of Household
</div>
```

This is my attempt at using them, but I can see the piece that is missing, the actual part where I would connect them to the code. How do I connect them? If someone could give me one example, I'm sure I could figure out the others. The following code is the taxes for a single filer, how would I connect the "single" button to the code?

```
<body>
    <div id="GrossIncome">
  <form name="GrossIncomeForm">
     <input type="text" name="answer box" />
    <button>Calculate</button>
   </form>
  <h4>Taxes Paid: $<span id="TaxesPaid">0.00</span></h4>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.querySelector('#GrossIncome form button').onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var IncomeInput, TaxableIncome, TaxableIncomeAdjusted, TaxesPaid;
  IncomeInput = document.querySelector('#GrossIncome input').value;
  TaxableIncome = (IncomeInput.length) ? parseInt(IncomeInput, 10) : 0;
   TaxableIncomeAdjusted = TaxableIncome - 12000;

  if ( TaxableIncomeAdjusted > 500000 )
TaxesPaid = (TaxableIncomeAdjusted - 500000) * 0.37 + 150689.5;
  if ( TaxableIncomeAdjusted <= 500000 )
TaxesPaid = (TaxableIncomeAdjusted - 200000) * 0.35 + 45689.5;
  if ( TaxableIncomeAdjusted <= 200000 )
TaxesPaid = (TaxableIncomeAdjusted - 157500) * 0.32 + 32089.5;
   if ( TaxableIncomeAdjusted <= 157500 )
TaxesPaid = (TaxableIncomeAdjusted - 82500) * 0.24 + 14089.5;
   if ( TaxableIncomeAdjusted <= 82500 )
TaxesPaid = (TaxableIncomeAdjusted - 38700) * 0.22 + 4453.5;
  if ( TaxableIncomeAdjusted <= 38700 )
TaxesPaid = (TaxableIncomeAdjusted - 9525) * 0.12 + 952.5;
  if ( TaxableIncomeAdjusted <= 9525 )
TaxesPaid = TaxableIncomeAdjusted * 0.1;


  TaxesPaid = Math.max(TaxesPaid, 0).toFixed(2);

   document.querySelector('#TaxesPaid').innerHTML = TaxesPaid;
};

</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would get it the same way you get a text input field:

```
let status = document.querySelector('#status input:checked').value
```

- `#status` the wrapper div
- `input` the input tag
- `:checked` the checked radio

This will return either **Single**, **MFJ**, **HOH**. You will then just need to use an `if` or `switch` statement to do what you want when one is selected.

Here is an example that will output the selected value when clicked:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#status input')).forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let status = document.querySelector('#status input:checked').value
    if (status == 'Single') {
      console.log('I am Single')
    } else if (status == 'MFJ') {
      console.log('I am Married Filing Jointly')
    } else if (status == 'HOH') {
      console.log('I am Head of Household')
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="status">
  <input type="radio" id="Single" name="status" value="Single" checked="checked"> Single
  <input type="radio" id="MFJ" name="status" value="MFJ"> Married Filing Jointly
  <input type="radio" id="HOH" name="status" value="HOH"> Head of Household
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use a change event and then run an if statement to see wish one is checked and then execute a function according to the radio button checked

```js
document.getElementById("status").addEventListener('change',function(){
   if(document.getElementById("Single").checked){
     console.log('single checked')
     // Do something if this one is checked
   }
 if(document.getElementById("MFJ").checked){
     console.log('Married Filing Jointly checked')
      // Do something if this one is checked
   }
   if(document.getElementById("HOH").checked){
     console.log('Head of Household checked')
      // Do something if this one is checked
   }
 })
```

```html
<div id="status">
<form id="status">
<input type="radio" id="Single" name="status" value="Single" checked="checked"> Single
<input type="radio" id="MFJ" name="status" value="MFJ"> Married Filing Jointly
<input type="radio" id="HOH" name="status" value="HOH"> Head of Household
<form>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post, I hope I am replying and not just adding another comment-- but where you have "Do something if this one is checked" is that where I would put my JS code?

Comment: @VCSchick do it inside the if statement , for example when single is checked do something inside the if statement .. execute a function or do some calculation ect ..

Answer (score 0):

```
var ch = document.getElementsByName('status');

for (var i = ch.length; i--;) {
    ch[i].onchange = function() {
        alert(this.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: please annotate your code. It also seems that it will generate an error, so please test it before suggesting